# Remove space after list on the table but \vspace gave no result

Tags: tables, longtable, itemize, vspace

As you can see [here](https://ibb.co/tDR8v9F) after Item 1, Item 2, and Item 3, there is a vertical space and i want to remove it.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable, array,enumitem, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\endgraf\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{longtable}{p{2cm}P{11cm}}
                \caption{\label{tab}This is a table}\\
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{\parbox[H]{2cm}{\centering \textbf{Column 1}}}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\parbox[H]{11cm}{\centering \textbf{Column 2}}}\\
                \hline \hline
                \endfirsthead
                \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{\parbox[H]{2cm}{\centering Column 1}}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\parbox[H]{11cm}{\centering Column 2}}\\
                \hline \hline
                \endhead 
                Point 1 & 
                \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt, nosep]
                    \item ITEM 1
                    \item ITEM 2
                    \item ITEM 3
                \end{itemize}
            \vspace{-2cm} \\     
                \hline
                Point 2 & Explanation  \\
                \hline
                Point 3 & Explanation \\
                \hline
                Point 4 & Explanation \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{longtable}
        \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated to the question but don't surround `longtable` with `center` it has no affect on the alignment,just adds spurious vertical space.

Comment: `\parbox[H]` parbox does not have an H option (it does not actually check the values given so it is silently ignored) (you do not need parbox at all, as you are already in a p column, so every cell is a parbox)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks sir. But i need parbox to centering the top row. Only the top row. The body part still left alignment. So how is it?

Comment: Oh sorry. I've just tried that. Didn't affect anything.

Comment: you can just use `\centering` you are already in a parbox

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok thanks. But there's still blank space under the list.

Comment: sure I was just going to post an answer about that but @leandris beat me by 10sec:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest defining an own custom list for the use in table cells. In the following MWE, I also corrected the width of the second cell to make sure the table does not exceed the textwidth. Regarding teh first rwo: Neither `\centering` no `\parbox` should be needed here. A simple `\multicolumn{c}` that you also used already horizontally centers its contents.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable, array,enumitem, booktabs}

\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{label=\textbullet, noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt, nosep, before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}, after=\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
            \begin{longtable}{p{2cm}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm-4\tabcolsep}}
                \caption{\label{tab}This is a table}\\
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 1}}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 2}}\\
                \hline \hline
                \endfirsthead
                \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 1}}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 2}}\\
                \hline \hline
                \endhead 
                Point 1 & 
                \begin{tabitem}
                    \item ITEM 1
                    \item ITEM 2
                    \item ITEM 3
                \end{tabitem}\\     
                \hline
                Point 2 & Explanation  \\
                \hline
                Point 3 & Explanation \\
                \hline
                Point 4 & Explanation \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Here is a also a second variant only using horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable, array,enumitem, booktabs}

\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{label=\textbullet, noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt, nosep, before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}, after=\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
            \begin{longtable}{p{2cm}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm-4\tabcolsep}}
                \caption{\label{tab}This is a table}\\
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 1}}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 2}}\\
                \midrule
                \endfirsthead
                \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 1}}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 2}}\\
                \midrule
                \endhead 
                \bottomrule
                \endfoot
                Point 1 & 
                \begin{tabitem}
                    \item ITEM 1
                    \item ITEM 2
                    \item ITEM 3
                \end{tabitem}\\     
               \midrule
                Point 2 & Explanation  \\
               \midrule
                Point 3 & Explanation \\
               \midrule
                Point 4 & Explanation \\
                
            \end{longtable}         
            
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much leandriis. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Oh wait. Can you explain a little bit about this : `p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm-4\tabcolsep}}`

Comment: I used `\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm-4\tabcolsep` to calculate the width of the second column. To make sure, the whole table is exactly as wide as the second column, I subsctracted 2 cm (width of the first column) from `\textwidth`.  Since a p{2cm} table column is actually wider than 2 cm (There is some small horizontal white space to the left and right of the 2 cm wide text. The default is 6pt, but can be changed by adjusting the value of `\tabcolsep`), we also have to substract `4*\tabcolsep`(2 columns with `\tabcolsep` on either side).