# Typesetting itemized and non-itemized content in a table

Tags: tables, itemize, enumitem

I am trying to layout a table that contains itemized lists is some cells of the table. I want to have both itemized and non itemized element of the table to align on to and avoid white space at the bottom of the itemized list. My question is, how can I get rid of the space marked in red in the following figure, resulting from my table layout code?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{compactitemize}{\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*]}{\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{l|p{.3\textwidth}p{.3\textwidth}}
    \hline\hline
    Section & Item list A & Item list B \\
    \hline\hline
    Section one & \begin{compactitemize} \item A.1 \item A.2 \item A.3 \end{compactitemize} & 
      \begin{compactitemize} \item B.1 \item B.2 \item B.3 \end{compactitemize} \\
    \hline
    Section two & \begin{compactitemize} \item A.1 \item A.2 \item A.3 \end{compactitemize} & 
      \begin{compactitemize} \item B.1 \item B.2 \item B.3 \end{compactitemize} \\
    \hline\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may be interested in the following answer to a related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576248/134144

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, if I've well understood what you want:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
    \makeatother
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \newenvironment{compactitemize}{\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}]}{\end{itemize}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
      \begin{tabular}{l|>{\compress}p{.3\textwidth}>{\compress}p{.3\textwidth}}
        \hline\hline
        Section & Item list A & Item list B \\
        \hline\hline
        Section one & \begin{compactitemize} \item A.1 \item A.2 \item A.3 \end{compactitemize} &
          \begin{compactitemize} \item B.1 \item B.2 \item B.3 \end{compactitemize} \\
        \hline
        Section two & \begin{compactitemize} \item A.1 \item A.2 \item A.3 \end{compactitemize} &
          \begin{compactitemize} \item B.1 \item B.2 \item B.3 \end{compactitemize} \\
        \hline\hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]